# Best cross-platform solution for building 3D toolsets?

Tags: 3d, unity, tools

I am looking to develop an in-browser game in Unity3D, but I would like to write my builder tools for my project on a more powerful platform.

The assets I am building for the game are not traditional 3D models, so I'll probably be creating my own format. I was thinking about writing something in Blender or Maya, but that is a lot of overhead for what I want to do.

A Unity3D desktop app was also a possibility, but at the end of the day I decided I wanted to build it outside of the game engine.

Since the Unity3D app is going to be cross platform, I would like the tool to be as well.

Saying that, does anyone know of a 3D library/platform that will run well on Windows and OS X?

Comment: So... you want to build a Unity game but not use Unity?

Comment: When you say "not traditional 3D models", what do you mean?  How would you import these models into Unity?  What exactly do you want to do that you feel that Unity isn't suited for?

Comment: The game is in unity, but for the content I want to make a desktop app that might be more powerful than mono C#.  Also, I am doing procedural content. so I load the file into unity at runtime and it creates the mesh and/or texture that the game needs.

Comment: It's hard to see a better option than using a Unity3D desktop app, given that you are familiar with Unity, file interchange with your WebPlayer will be trivially easy, and you need less than a Blender-scale 3D editor. You may need to give more detail about what you are making. If for example, it's like Spore's creators, Unity would be perfect.

Comment: I'm basically creating a minecraftish builder.  It is more for "pixelated" 3D art than it is for minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

A Unity3D desktop app would be the logical choice, despite your decision not to, the reasoning of which is unclear.